# AMD GPU problems

Tags: amd-graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I have a problem with AMD (Radeon R7 240) graphics unit. Ubuntu is running CPU rendering and the resolution is terrible. The screen almost does not refresh. I went through the extremely difficult taks to download the AMD drivers from their website. I followed the instructions and installed them but after a sudo reboot I got stuck with the following error:
failed to start user manager for uid 121
And the system refuses to load any further

Edit:
Ubuntu version: 18.04.2
Link to AMD drivers: https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-r7-series/amd-radeon-r7-200-series/amd-radeon-r7-240
Scroll to the bottom and you will see the Ubuntu drivers

Comment: Is this related to Ubuntu, and if yes, which release?

Comment: Were these drivers used: https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ? Please click [edit] and update your question to let us know, along with specifying which version of Ubuntu you have installed. Please do not click Add Comment to respond, since old comments can get shoved off screen by new comments. Please also run this command and add the result to the question: _sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer_

Comment: I can't access the terminal to write commands